# select list set selected item angular 2 ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

This is my current code:

```
<select name="role" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [ngValue]="role" [attr.selected]="role == user.role ? 'true' : 'false'">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I'm loading all the roles in an array, and the user class has a Role attribute (which is not loaded like `user.role = roles[0]` but just through the backend data).

The problem is that the selected attribute is not working, and my select is not going to the correct role. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove

```ts
[attr.selected]="role == user.role ? 'true' : 'false'"
```

and assign the selected role to `user.role` and `ngModel` will make the matching item the selected one.

If the `role` is an object, the assigned instance needs to be identical.

See also the recently added custom comparison https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13268
**available since 4.0.0-beta.7**

```ts
<select [compareWith]="compareFn" ...
```

```ts
compareFn(val1, val2): boolean {
  return val1 && val2 ? val1.id === val2.id : val1 === val2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense that it doesn't work since the objects are not the same reference. Can I use a `ngComparator` for this? Or what would be the syntax?

Comment: I updated my answer. It should be included in 4.0.0-beta.7

Comment: Just one question, did you test this out? I tried it but couldn't get it to work with the `[compareWith]` function. Apparently my `val2` is always null =/

Comment: Are you using Angular 4.0.0-beta.7? I haven't tested it, but the code is from an example in the linked PR, from the guy who implemented this feature.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `[attr.selected]`. `[(ngModel)]="user.role"` is two-way data-binding, it will select the matched option from your list if value is equal to `user.role`. And you can also use basic `[value]`

```
<select name="role" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for [ngValue]? I didn't find it. When should I use it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedDevice" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel2">
    <option [value]="i" *ngFor="let i of devices">{{i}}</option>
</select>

onChange(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedDevice = newValue;\
}
```